# How can I get my JS bingo machine to output my called numbers?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm working on this bingo machine script, but it's not outputting my called numbers or numbers previously called in my output divs. This is part of my JS certification, and I've really hit a wall here. How can I proceed?

I've tried putting regular text output into my callNum and numCalled functions to see if the functions are being called properly / outputting properly with no result.

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
<div id="buttons">
  <button onClick="callNum()">
    Call bingo number
  </button>
  <button onClick="numCalled()">
    Numbers called
  </button>
  <button onClick="setGame()">
    Start/Reset Game
  </button>
</div>
<div id="bingonumber"></div>
<div id="numberscalled"></div>
<script>
    const numbers = new Set()
      .add("B1")
      .add("B2")
      .add("B3")
      .add("B4")
      .add("B5")
      .add("B6")
      .add("B7")
      .add("B8")
      .add("B9")
      .add("B10")
      .add("B11")
      .add("B12")
      .add("B13")
      .add("B14")
      .add("B15")
      .add("I16")
      .add("I17")
      .add("I18")
      .add("I19")
      .add("I20")
      .add("I21")
      .add("I22")
      .add("I23")
      .add("I24")
      .add("I25")
      .add("I26")
      .add("I27")
      .add("I28")
      .add("I29")
      .add("I30")
      .add("N31")
      .add("N32")
      .add("N33")
      .add("N35")
      .add("N35")
      .add("N36")
      .add("N37")
      .add("N38")
      .add("N39")
      .add("N40")
      .add("N41")
      .add("N42")
      .add("N43")
      .add("N44")
      .add("N45")
      .add("G46")
      .add("G47")
      .add("G48")
      .add("G49")
      .add("G50")
      .add("G51")
      .add("G52")
      .add("G53")
      .add("G54")
      .add("G55")
      .add("G56")
      .add("G57")
      .add("G58")
      .add("G59")
      .add("G60")
      .add("O61")
      .add("O62")
      .add("O63")
      .add("O64")
      .add("O65")
      .add("O66")
      .add("O67")
      .add("O68")
      .add("O69")
      .add("O70")
      .add("O71")
      .add("O72")
      .add("O73")
      .add("O74")
      .add("O75")
    let curnum = new Array([]);
    let prevnum = new Array([]);

    function setGame() {
        let curnum = Array.from(numbers);
        let prevnum = [];
        document.getElementById('bingonumber').innerHTML = "Game time started";
    }

    function callNum() {
      var index = Math.floor(Math.random() * curnum.length);
      let remove = curnum.splice(index, 1);
      document.getElementById('bingonumber').innerHTML =  remove;
      prevnum.push(remove);
    }

    function numCalled() {
      let prevoutput = "";
      for (x = 0; x < prevnum.length; x++) {
        prevoutput += prevnum[x];
      }
      document.getElementById('numberscalled').innerHTML = output;
    }
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

I would expect the output of callNum to give me the spliced bingo number out of the curnum array, but it's not showing. numCalled isn't outputting anything either.

Comment: @ChrisF ok, i got you .

Answer (score 0):

`remove` is coming out as an array, so it looks like ["B4"] for example. Try `document.getElementById('bingonumber').innerHTML =  remove[0];` and see if you can figure it out from there

Answer (score 0):

Two issues I see with your code.

1. You are re-declaring your curnum and prevnum variables inside the setGame function. And since you are using the `let` declaration they only maintain scope within that function. Simply remove the `let` from inside that function

```
    function setGame() {
          curnum = Array.from(numbers);
          prevnum = [];
          document.getElementById('bingonumber').innerHTML = "Game time started";
     }
```

2. The second issue isn't related to your question but you will fail to display previous numbers called because your variable is named `prevoutput` but you reference an undefined variable `output` change this line

`document.getElementById('numberscalled').innerHTML = output;`

to

`document.getElementById('numberscalled').innerHTML = prevoutput;`

Comment: also adding this line to the setGame function will clear the previous numbers block, otherwise you will display last games previous numbers: `document.getElementById('numberscalled').innerHTML = ""`

Comment: That helped immensely, thank you! I can play Bingo now!

Comment: If you're interested in learning let vs var vs const here is a blog post on the topic: https://medium.com/@josephcardillo/the-difference-between-function-and-block-scope-in-javascript-4296b2322abe

Answer (score 0):

There's a problem in the usage of let in your functions body, it's block scoped.
Here is a more explicit one with template string to display the numbers one on each other.

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
<div id="buttons">
  <button onClick="callNum()">
    Call bingo number
  </button>
  <button onClick="numCalled()">
    Numbers called
  </button>
  <button onClick="setGame()">
    Start/Reset Game
  </button>
</div>
<div id="bingonumber"></div>
<div id="numberscalled"></div>
<script>
    const numbers = new Set()
      .add("B1")
      .add("B2")
      .add("B3")
      .add("B4")
      .add("B5")
      .add("B6")
      .add("B7")
      .add("B8")
      .add("B9")
      .add("B10")
      .add("B11")
      .add("B12")
      .add("B13")
      .add("B14")
      .add("B15")
      .add("I16")
      .add("I17")
      .add("I18")
      .add("I19")
      .add("I20")
      .add("I21")
      .add("I22")
      .add("I23")
      .add("I24")
      .add("I25")
      .add("I26")
      .add("I27")
      .add("I28")
      .add("I29")
      .add("I30")
      .add("N31")
      .add("N32")
      .add("N33")
      .add("N35")
      .add("N35")
      .add("N36")
      .add("N37")
      .add("N38")
      .add("N39")
      .add("N40")
      .add("N41")
      .add("N42")
      .add("N43")
      .add("N44")
      .add("N45")
      .add("G46")
      .add("G47")
      .add("G48")
      .add("G49")
      .add("G50")
      .add("G51")
      .add("G52")
      .add("G53")
      .add("G54")
      .add("G55")
      .add("G56")
      .add("G57")
      .add("G58")
      .add("G59")
      .add("G60")
      .add("O61")
      .add("O62")
      .add("O63")
      .add("O64")
      .add("O65")
      .add("O66")
      .add("O67")
      .add("O68")
      .add("O69")
      .add("O70")
      .add("O71")
      .add("O72")
      .add("O73")
      .add("O74")
      .add("O75")
    let currentNumber = []
    let previousNumber = []

    function setGame() {
        currentNumber = Array.from(numbers);
        previousNumber = [];
        document.getElementById('bingonumber').innerHTML = "Game time started";
    }

    function callNum() {
      var index = Math.floor(Math.random() * currentNumber.length);
      var remove = currentNumber.splice(index, 1);
      document.getElementById('bingonumber').innerHTML =  remove;
      previousNumber.push(remove);
    }

    function numCalled() {
      var prevoutput = "";
      for (x = 0; x < previousNumber.length; x++) {
        prevoutput += `${previousNumber[x]}<br/>`;
      }
      document.getElementById('numberscalled').innerHTML = prevoutput;
    }
</script>
</body>
</html>
```